# webhook exec git pull not working when called from the browser

Tags: php, git, exec, git-pull, webhooks

i searched on the internet for hours to find a good solution but all the topics that allready exits dont help for me

i try to build a webhook to update my website by doing a git pull that is called afther a git hook when commits pushed to my live branche. But it isn't working when i try to call git pull by requesting my php script in the browser.

apache is running as www-data, all the rights a set up well.

the php script is running good when i try to run it as www data user with `su - www-data` and than `php webHook.php`

but when i call it in the browser, i get no response. I guess apache is blocking

this is the command i use in the php script:

```
echo shell_exec('cd /home/my-site/public_html && git pull');
```

the result is empty and the git repository is not pulled at all.

but if i try this:

```
echo shell_exec('cd /home/my-site/public_html && git');
```

i got this result

> usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path] [-p|--p..........

so everything is working, except the git pull command.

the respository is saved on another server with atlassian stash. and i saved the password with `git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=360000000"`

Comment: any particular reason you want to do that from the front end?

Comment: @Kisaragi yes because i want to call the webhook from a Atlassian Stash add-on called 'Post-Receive WebHooks'. The add-on does simple POST commit related information to other systems via a simple WebHook URL.

Comment: can someone help me please? Still not working.